# Improve efficiency linking data from two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one of hospital stays, and the other of lab results. I need to identify which hospital stay a lab result takes place in, and copy the admission and discharge dates from the hospital data frame into the row for the relevant lab result.

I am doing this with a for loop to walk through the lab results, and then if statements and subsets that look for matching entries (by patient SSN and surrounding dates) in the hospital records.

This is quite a large data set and using the for loop is very slow. Is there a way to speed this kind of problem up? (I have several similar problems, so would love an answer.)

Sample data added, note that there are multiple hospital records for each patient with the goal being to get the dates from the record where the dates overlap the lab date. In this example, the resulting data frame should only have admission and discharge dates for patient 1, as patient 2 has no hospital data, and patient 3's records do not overlap the lab date.

```
testDate <- as.Date(c("2017-01-15", "2017-01-15", "2017-01-15"))
patientSSN <- c("1","2","3")
labs <- data.frame(patientSSN, testDate)

#   patientSSN   testDate
# 1          1 2017-01-15
# 2          2 2017-01-15
# 3          3 2017-01-15

patientSSN <- c("1","1","3","3")
admissionDate <- as.Date(c("2017-01-07", "2017-02-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-16"))
dischargeDate <- as.Date(c("2017-01-16", "2017-02-10", "2016-12-15", "2017-02-01"))
hospitalRec <- data.frame(patientSSN, admissionDate, dischargeDate)

for (I in 1:nrow(labs)) {
labs[I,]$admissionDate <- hospitalRec[hospitalRec$patientSSN == labs[I,]$patientSSN & hospitalRec$admissionDate <= labs[I,]$testDate & hospitalRec$dischargeDate >= labs[I,]$testDate,]$admissionDate

labs[I,]$admissionDate <- hospitalRec[hospitalRec$PatientSSN == labs[I,]$PatientSSN & hospitalRec$admissionDate <= labs[I,]$testDate & hospitalRec$dischargeDate >= labs[I,]$testDate,]$dischargeDate

}
```

The desired data frame would look like:

```
labs:
    patientSSN  testDate   admissionDate  dischargeDate
    1           2017-01-15 2017-01-07     2017-01-16
    2           2017-01-15 NA             NA
    3           2017-01-15 NA             NA
```

Notice, in the real data, there is also the problem of multiple hospital records qualifying (discharges between departments) these records would have the same admission date, but different discharge times with the latest one being important. But first things first...

Comment: Could you please show sample data, and what is expected output? It will help others to assist you properly.

Comment: try merging the two dataframes using `dplyr`'s `join` functions. if you reproduce sample data, we can help with that.

Comment: sample data provided. merging won't work as it would not recognize the date problem.

Answer (score 1):

A non equi join works, for example with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(labs); setDT(hospitalRec)

labs[hospitalRec, on=.(patientSSN, testDate >= admissionDate, testDate <= dischargeDate),
  `:=`(aDate = i.admissionDate, dDate = i.dischargeDate)]

   patientSSN   testDate      aDate      dDate
1:          1 2017-01-15 2017-01-07 2017-01-16
2:          2 2017-01-15       <NA>       <NA>
3:          3 2017-01-15       <NA>       <NA>
```

> in the real data, there is also the problem of multiple hospital records qualifying (discharges between departments) these records would have the same admission date, but different discharge times with the latest one being important.

If `hospitalRec` is sorted, adding `mult="last"` above should work. See `?data.table` for full documentation. Alternately, you could just create a version of the hospital records that excludes these "duplicates", like ... sort and then

```
lastRec = unique(hospitalRec, by=c("patientSSN", "admissionDate"), fromLast=TRUE))
```

The `setorder` function is the standard tool for sorting data.tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is similar to what your df looks like, use `dplyr::left_join`:

```
hospital_data <- data.frame(PatientSSN  = c('1234567890','9876543210'),
                            admit = c('8/1/17','8/5/17'),
                            discharge = c('8/10/17','8/15/17'))

lab_data <- data.frame(specimen_id = c('foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4','foo5','foo6','foo7'),
                       PatientSSN = c('1234567890','1234567890','1234567890','9876543210','9876543210','9876543210','8527419600'),
                       test = c('hemoglobin','inr','platelette','hemoglobin','inr','platelette','inr'))

lab_data %>% left_join(hospital_data)

 specimen_id PatientSSN       test  admit discharge
1        foo1  1234567890 hemoglobin 8/1/17   8/10/17
2        foo2  1234567890        inr 8/1/17   8/10/17
3        foo3  1234567890 platelette 8/1/17   8/10/17
4        foo4  9876543210 hemoglobin 8/5/17   8/15/17
5        foo5  9876543210        inr 8/5/17   8/15/17
6        foo6  9876543210 platelette 8/5/17   8/15/17
7        foo7  8527419600        inr   <NA>      <NA>
```

Note that your id variable `(PatientSSN)` are the same in each table.

Comment: This ignores the date problem. The labresults have dates as well, and the only admit and discharge dates that should be selected are ones surrounding the lab's date. a simple merge does not do this (to my knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

OK- here's a method. Just a quick heads up, though; it's pretty unlikely that you'll ever work with EMR data that doesn't have an ID variable specific to a visit/account. I would look to use that as the unique identifier before I used SSN. Nevertheless; this should work. I used the data you provided above.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(labs)){

  #finding the ID (ssn)

  ssn_match_df <- hospitalRec[which(as.character(labs$patientSSN[i]) == as.character(hospitalRec$patientSSN)),]

  #finding record in table where the test date fall between the admit/discharge
  ssn_match_df <- ssn_match_df[which(labs$testDate[i] >= ssn_match_df$admissionDate &
                                       labs$testDate[i] <= ssn_match_df$dischargeDate),]

  if(nrow(ssn_match_df)>0){
    labs[i,3] <- as.character(ssn_match_df[1,2])
    labs[i,4] <- as.character(ssn_match_df[1,3])
  } else {
    labs[i,3] <- NA
    labs[i,4] <- NA
  }


}

colnames(labs)[3] <- 'admitDate'
colnames(labs)[4] <- 'dischargeDate'
```

Comment: So this would be nearly twice as fast because it only scans the inpatient data frame once?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. No way around the for loop I see.  As for SSN, when you want to match the patient across multiple facilities, using each facility's internal identifier is not preferred.